# await is not waiting for function to complete

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, promise, async-await

So, I'm doing some work where a User can make an inscription to a gym class which it has 'x' available spaces(For example 15) . After the inscription is complete, the available spaces decreases by 1. The problem I'm facing, is after the inscription, the available spaces are not decreasing right away.

My code is like this:

**INSCRIPTION SERVICE**

```
inscripcionAClase(clase, username) {
    var nuevaInscripcion = {
      id: clase._id,
      username: username
    };

    this.postInscripcion(nuevaInscripcion)
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        alert('Inscripto con exito!');
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

**GET CLASSES SERVICE**

```
 async obtenerListadoClases(categoria) {


    var clasesDB;

    await this.getClases(categoria).toPromise().then((resp: any) => {
      clasesDB = resp.clasesDB;
    })
    return  clasesDB;
  }
```

**USING GET CLASSES SERVICE**

```
async obtenerClases(categoria) {

    this.listadoClases = await this.claseServicio.obtenerListadoClases(categoria);

    console.log(this.listadoClases, 'obtengo listado');
  }
```

**ALERT CONTROLLER**

```
 async inscripcionAlert(clase) {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Atención',
      message: 'Confirme para inscribirse a la clase',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Aceptar',
          handler: async () => {
            await this.inscripcionServicio.inscripcionAClase(clase, this.username); // **Works fine**
            await this.obtenerClases(this.categoria) // **Classes are not refreshing after the inscription is made**

          }
        }, {
          text: 'Cancelar'
        }
      ]
    });
    await alert.present();
  }
```

One thing I've noticed is, if I write my alert controller class like this ( With setTimeOut at get classes), it works perfectly. So I think is a delay problem with the promises, but Im using the await keyword before, but it doesnt do the "await" function.

```
 async inscripcionAlert(clase) {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Atención',
      message: 'Confirme para inscribirse a la clase',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Aceptar',
          handler: async () => {
            await this.inscripcionServicio.inscripcionAClase(clase, this.username);
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.obtenerListadoClases(this.categoria)
            }, 2500);


          }
        }, {
          text: 'Cancelar'
        }
      ]
    });
    await alert.present();
  }
```

Comment: The angular way of doing things would be to work with observables, rather than promises.